Not able to set DCom Configuration Permissions "Full Control" using Powershell
As a novice and first attempt at a Powershell script, I'm attempting to to set Dcom Config for the following:
Launch and Activation Permissions
Access Permissions
Configuration Permissions
The issue is with trying to set the Configuration Permissions for Full Control for a specific user. The user is added to the Configuration Permissions, but the "Full Control" check is not being done.
The following is current script that I've attempted to use:
$wmi = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DCOMApplicationSetting -Filter "AppId='{Enter App ID here}'" -EnableAllPrivileges)

# Use the Get Descriptors method to set the objects and store
$descL = $wmi.GetLaunchSecurityDescriptor().descriptor
$descC = $wmi.GetConfigurationSecurityDescriptor().descriptor
$descA = $wmi.GetAccessSecurityDescriptor().descriptor

# Create a special object to hold trustee related information. set trustee we want to apply
$trusteeObj = ([wmiclass]'Win32_Trustee').psbase.CreateInstance()
$trusteeObj.Domain = "$PCName"
$trusteeObj.Name = "TCPComUser"

# Create a special object to store ACL stuff
$ace = ([wmiclass]'Win32_ACE').psbase.CreateInstance()

# Set the access mask desired(Launch & Local Activation allowed).
$ace.AccessMask = 11

# Set Trustee to what we created earlier then append to the existing ACL configuration.
$ace.Trustee = $trusteeObj
$descL.DACL += [System.Management.ManagementBaseObject]$ace
$descC.DACL += [System.Management.ManagementBaseObject]$ace
$descA.DACL += [System.Management.ManagementBaseObject]$ace

# Use the Set Descriptors method to set all the stuff we created and appended in stone
$wmi.SetLaunchSecurityDescriptor($descL)
$wmi.SetConfigurationSecurityDescriptor($descC)
$wmi.SetAccessSecurityDescriptor($descA)


You'll want $ace.AccessMask = 2032127 to encode full control ( =all permissions combined)

Thanks for the feedback Mathias. Swapping out the value of 11 as shown in the code snippet and replacing with the 203127 didn't resolve the issue and still not able to set the Configuration Permissions for "Full Control" in the Dcom Config.    Although adding the suggested value of 203127 did check the "remote launch" under the "launch and activation permissions" section of the Dcom Config.

What value do you see for the AccessMask property if you read an existing ACE with "Full Control" checked?

Hello, not sure how to read in an existing ACE. I did find another way though. I ended up adding registry drive for HKCR and then set here:

$acl = Get-Acl "HKCR:\APPId{APPId}"
$person = [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]"UserInfo"
$access = [System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights]"FullControl"
$inheritance =[System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit"$propagation = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]"None"
$type = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]"Allow"
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule($person,$access,$inheritance,$propagation,$type)
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
$acl |Set-Acl
